# MFC toolbar on top row with right align

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, toolbar

By default, MFC toolbar are docked on top row left align. Could anyone please tell me how to dock the MFC toolbar on top row with right align (meaning that all toolbar buttons are align to right on the top row)?

Answer (score 1):

If u just want the tool bar at the right top corner, u can use the below code in CMainFrame

```
if (!m_wndRSToolBar.CreateEx(this, TTBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP
    | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMI,Rect(700,0,0,0),IDR_MAINFRAME) ||    !m_wndRSToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME1))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```